# User control - calling a vb linkbutton's(within a user control) click event from javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, user-controls

how can i call a VB function - `deleteevent()` in usercontrol.ascx.vb from a javascript function in `clickhandler(e)` in usercontrol.ascx. **The call should cause a postback** because I need the usercontrol to display the changes.

I am currently trying to do it by using a linkbutton with style display:none, and calling its click event from the javascript function. But i dunno how to call the click event.

I had to pass a value to the vb function from the javascript, but i am taking care of it using a hiddenfield.

the environment is asp.net 3.0 language:vb

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this two links about calling codebehind methods with JQuery :

[Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

[Using jQuery to Call ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods](http://weblogs.asp.net/craigshoemaker/archive/2008/09/29/using-jquery-to-call-asp-net-ajax-page-methods.aspx)

You should call aspx instead of ascx methods. beacuse at runtime all user controls (ascx) merged to your page (aspx).

If you have a user control with multiple instances in a page, you should use a parameter to define context of method in each usercontrol. Maybe user control's clientID.

Answer (score 1):

This one is slightly tricky, but kinda fun.

Basically, you need to:

1. Implement IPostBackEventHandler on the control where you want to raise the event
2. Create a postback reference for the control
3. Call the postback reference, either via a hyperlink or jscript
4. In the code behind, handle the postback reference and call your code

   ```
   Public Class MyControl
   Inherits UserControl
   Implements IPostBackEventHandler

   Public Sub RaisePostBackEvent(ByVal eventArgument As String) Implements System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent

       ' Call deleteEvent here
       DeleteEvent(eventArgument)  ' This will contain "SomeArgumentYouWantToPassToDeleteEvent"

   End Sub

   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
       Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript

       Dim a As New HtmlAnchor()
       a.ID = "myanchor1"
       a.InnerText = "Delete Event"
       a.HRef = cs.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Me, "SomeArgumentYouWantToPassToDeleteEvent")

       ' You could alternatively construct some jscript and output it.

       Controls.Add(a)

   End Sub
   End Class
   ```

For more info, see here: [ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153112.aspx)