# Using Javascript, how can I simulate clicking on a server-side link button by using eval function in client-side?

Tags: javascript, eval

vascript, how can I simulate clicking on a server-side link button by using eval function in client-side?

Comment: You should give some more details, exactly what is the 'click' meant to do?

Comment: What on earth is a "server-side link button"?

Comment: @Arkaaito -- It's most likely a reference to ASP.NET, where there is a control referred to as a LinkButton.  It's a client-side anchor that has server-side event bindings.  Basically, ASP.NET maps the client onclick to a server-side C#/VB.NET function, which I'm guessing is what he's referring to.

Comment: Ahhhhh!  That makes perfect sense.  Sorry, I've been working at a PHP shop for the last *two years*, so any ASP.NET knowledge I once had has dribbled out my ears.  (And since it didn't have the language tag, it didn't occur to me that he meant something language-specific.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has been asked and answered before here on SO...

- [User control - calling a vb linkbutton's(within a user control) click event from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739943/user-control-calling-a-vb-linkbuttonswithin-a-user-control-click-event-from)
- [Invoking button click on ASP.net client side programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999069/invoking-button-click-on-asp-net-client-side-programmatically)
- [Calling a vb linkbutton’s(within a user control) click event from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743155/calling-a-vb-linkbuttonswithin-a-user-control-click-event-from-javascript)